# php-webdriver webdriver Chrome dev tools protocol , how can i listen an event of devtools , it doesn't have listen command

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools, addeventlistener, facebook-php-webdriver

I use `php-webdriver` for test automation  on chrome, I want to listen to a chrome dev tools event, but the `php-webdrvier` does not a have a listen command, only execute, is there another way to listen to an event? I am interested in `tracing.datacollected` event specifically

I tried to find another way but I failed